# Optimize a search through a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a very large linked list and I have to continuously check if a specific node is in that list. 
The linked list contains a single int variable. I was thinking of maybe using an array to check if something has been added to another linked list(I don't know how I would do this). I know I can just use simple loops but that takes too long. Anyway to optimize the search by not continuously looping? I cannot use BSTs or any other abstract data type.

Comment: why can't you use other data types? Linked list is very bad for memory (memory for the pointer may be even larger than the data itself like in this case) and cache locality

Comment: Be careful when you say you "cannot use any other data type".  If you store meta data to speed up the search, then you are using another data structure.  IOW, anything you do to improve linear search will require using some auxiliary data, which is "another data type".

Comment: very large meaning less than 500 nodes, and I know that linked list isnt very good on memory but we arent allowed to use other data types

Comment: i should say abstract data type then, i will change my question

Comment: What is the original problem? This smells like an XY-type situation: you have a homework problem X, and vague instructions of solving it using Y, and got stuck on Y. Can you please clarify the entire problem?

Comment: I have a solution but it takes too long. I tried thinking of a way to search through a linked list that does require me to search the entire linked list every time for every item. i don't think me clarifying the entire problem would help as it doesn't really have anything to do with what i want. this problem is a separate issue. i am just trying to reduce the number of times i would have to search through a linked list as the runtime of my function is relatively high(1 min). Other functions are not at fault here as they have little or nothing to do with searching a linked list

Comment: there arent any repeated nodes in each linked list but the different linked lists can have the same thing stored(what im trying to filter out. if that makes any sense

Comment: Can you move the "specific node" to the front of the list ?  Or add a "last node found" pointer to the list base ?

Comment: i could but can you explain how that would help? im a bit confused, sorry

Comment: What is the actual goal of this assignment? To remove duplicates from multiple linked lists, each list having < 500 nodes? How many of these linked lists are there? Are the linked lists sorted, or are you allowed to sort the linked lists? If the linked lists are sorted, and there are `k` lists, then you could implement something similar to a `k` way merge, but instead of merging, deleting duplicates. There would need to be some rule for which list to remove duplicates from.

Comment: there are 2 linked lists and not sorted. we can do whatever we want with the linked list itself. i have heard that using an array and input values that have already been searched would reduce search time dramatically. is this true?

Comment: You say you _"have to continuously check if a specific node is in that list"_.  If by that you mean you are repeatedly checking for the _same_ node, then if on the first time you find it, you move it to the front of the list, then it won't take much finding next time you look.  If you are repeatedly looking for a small subset of nodes on the list, then moving the last one found to the front of the list will still help (if the list is long).